# gnu make, include and clean target

Tags: include, makefile

I am working on a system which is composed of many projects and makefiles. Each makefile includes .inc files from it`s dependencies. If a dependency is missing, it complains and tells the user to compile the dependency first. This part works ok. Problem is the clean target.

If a dependency is cleaned first and it`s inc file is deleted (since inc files include compile time options and hard paths, we prefer to delete them), then Makefile fails to load the .inc file and aborts. So the mechanism that makes sure we have the right dependencies, does not let us call the clean target -which does not require the dependencies-.

Is there any way to include or ignore .inc files according to the rule?

PS: Since we are already using "-" for error checking so that is not an option.

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but... Why should the makefile complain and tell the user to compile the dependency first? Why doesn't it just compile the dependency? and if you're using "-" (I assume you mean your makefiles contain directives like `-include foo.inc`) then how is it that Make aborts if the desired ".inc" file is missing?

Comment: The project is really big and everybody works on their isolated environments. So each makefile is only responsible for that part of the project. Makefiles used to compile dependencies, but we found out that people were abusing this and not paying attention to global dependencies. So we stopped.   Yes that is what I meant with "-", if the include fails, the version variable that is supposed to come from that particular inc file is empty. Then we complain and abort.

Answer (score 2):

the canonical way to prevent including when cleaning is as follows:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
include $(some .inc files)
endif
```

as described here https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals

although if i understand correctly the errors you are experiencing are not because of the failed includes, which you are already supressing with `-include`, but because your makefile is dependent on some values from the includes.

to help you fix that we will need some code which demonstrates the problem. please read here for how to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and http://www.sscce.org/